# How to import "useAccordionButton"?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

Using "react-bootstrap"

```
import { useAccordionButton } from 'react-bootstrap/AccordionButton';
```

Gives error message:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/AccordionButton'

```
npm list

bsn-gui@0.1.0 C:\goproj\src\github.com\amortaza\bsn-gui
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.14.1
├── @testing-library/react@11.2.7
├── @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3
├── bindings@1.5.0 extraneous
├── bootstrap@5.1.1
├── file-uri-to-path@1.0.0 extraneous
├── nan@2.15.0 extraneous
├── react-bootstrap-validation@0.1.11
├── react-bootstrap@1.6.3
├── react-dom@17.0.2
├── react-scripts@4.0.3
├── react-split@2.0.13
├── react@17.0.2
└── web-vitals@1.1.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Accordion.Button` is available in react-bootstrap v5 (v2.0.0-rc0)

[Accordion.Button](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/#accordion-button-props)

You have v4 `react-bootstrap@1.6.3` installed.

Uninstall the current version and install latest.

```
npm uninstall -S react-bootstrap
npm install -S react-bootstrap@2.0.0-rc.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your NPM list states you are using react-bootstrap@1.6.3 yet your code is referencing the [2.0.0-rc.0 API](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/#useaccordionbutton). Of course, as with all third-party tools, you must reference the documentation relevant to the version you choose to use. Refer to the [proper documentation for 1.6.3](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/accordion/), or change your version to 2.0.0-rc.0 if you need that API.